# Lambda expression and InvokeOperation

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, wcf-ria-services, invoke

I have this code and cannot figure out how it could be simplified via Lambda expression?

```
public void LoadEntities(QueryBuilder<Device> query, Action<ServiceLoadResult<Device>> callback, object state)
{
    InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>> obj = this.Context.GetAllDivisions();

    obj.Completed += new EventHandler(obj_Completed);   
}

void obj_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (sender is InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy> divisions = 
                new ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy>((sender as InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>).Value);
        }
    }
    catch  
    {                 
    }
}
```

Comment: What place in code do you want to simplify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a bit too broad, so I'm guessing here, but the only place for lambda expressions here is when hooking into the event. So instead of having a seperate obj_Completed method, you can do this:

```
    public void LoadEntities(QueryBuilder<Device> query, Action<ServiceLoadResult<Device>> callback, object state)
    {
        InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>> obj = this.Context.GetAllDivisions();

        obj.Completed += (sender, e) =>
        {
           try
           {
               if (sender is InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>)
               {
                   ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy> divisions = 
                       new ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy>((sender as InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>).Value);

               }
           }
           catch  
           {                 
           }
       } 
     }
```

Comment: @Peretz: Please accept an answer you see as correct. Don't copy/paste it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the final solution is here

```
    public void LoadEntities(QueryBuilder<Device> query, Action<ServiceLoadResult<Device>> callback, object state)
    {

    ((InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>)this.Context.GetAllDivisions()).Completed += (sender, e) =>
        {
             try
             {
                 if (sender is InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>)
                 {
                     ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy> divisions =
                         new ObservableCollection<DivisionHierarchy>((sender as InvokeOperation<List<DivisionHierarchy>>).Value);
                  }
              }
              catch
              {
              }
         };         
}
```